# What is wrong with this python function?

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables

I can't see where I would have gone wrong - other answers seem to point to this being an improper use of a global variable within a function but I'm pretty sure I haven't sinned in this way.

When I run this code it successfully prompts me for all the rows of data, but then the error happens as soon as it tries to run the 1st function...

Can somebody please point out to me what I have done wrong?

The error message I get is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'monthlyValue' referenced before assignment on line 17 in main.py
```

My entire program is this:

```
def calcMonthlyYearlyValues(weeklyVsYearlyVsQuarterly,initialValue):
  if(weeklyVsYearlyVsQuarterly.upper() == "W"):
    yearlyValue = initialValue * 52
    monthlyValue = round(float(yearlyValue / 12),2)
  elif (weeklyVsYearlyVsQuarterly.upper() == "Y"):
    yearlyValue = initialValue
    monthlyValue = round(float(yearlyValue / 12),2)
  elif (weeklyVsYearlyVsQuarterly.upper() == "Q"):
    yearlyValue = initialValue * 4
    monthlyValue = round(float(yearlyValue / 12),2)
  return monthlyValue, yearlyValue

def inputRowValues(rowDescription):
  print rowDescription
  rowName = input("Enter Item Name: ")
  rowPeriodType = input("W/ M/ Q/ Y for Weekly/ Monthly/ Quarterly or Yearly:")
  rowValue = float(input("Enter Amount: "))
  print ""
  return rowName, rowPeriodType, rowValue

row1Name, row1PeriodType, row1Value = inputRowValues("Row 1")
row2Name, row2PeriodType, row2Value = inputRowValues("Row 2")
row3Name, row3PeriodType, row3Value = inputRowValues("Row 3")
row4Name, row4PeriodType, row4Value = inputRowValues("Row 4")
row5Name, row5PeriodType, row5Value = inputRowValues("Row 5")
row1Monthly, row1Yearly  = calcMonthlyYearlyValues(row1PeriodType,row1Value)
row2Monthly, row2Yearly  = calcMonthlyYearlyValues(row2PeriodType,row2Value)
row3Monthly, row3Yearly  = calcMonthlyYearlyValues(row3PeriodType,row3Value)
row4Monthly, row4Yearly  = calcMonthlyYearlyValues(row4PeriodType,row4Value)
row5Monthly, row5Yearly  = calcMonthlyYearlyValues(row5PeriodType,row5Value)
column1 = "Item"
column2 = "Month"
column3 = "Year"

print "Monthly Budget"
print "========================================"
print "{0:<15}  {1:^10}  {2:^10}".format(column1, column2, column3)
print "========================================"
print "{0:<15} ${1:>10,.2f}  ${2:>10,.2f}".format(row1Name, row1Monthly, row1Yearly)
print "{0:<15} ${1:>10,.2f}  ${2:>10,.2f}".format(row2Name, row2Monthly, row2Yearly)
print "{0:<15} ${1:>10,.2f}  ${2:>10,.2f}".format(row3Name, row3Monthly, row3Yearly)
print "{0:<15} ${1:>10,.2f}  ${2:>10,.2f}".format(row4Name, row4Monthly, row4Yearly)
print "{0:<15} ${1:>10,.2f}  ${2:>10,.2f}".format(row5Name, row5Monthly, row5Yearly)
```

Comment: When `weeklyVsYearlyVsQuarterly` is `M` you don't assign values to `monthlyValue` and `yearlyValue`

Comment: Thank You!  Couldn't see the wood for the trees! A bit of an oversight.  Appreciate your quick answer!

Comment: Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nick's comment - I realised I was missing an elif as below:

```
def calcMonthlyYearlyValues(weeklyVsYearlyVsQuarterly,initialValue):
  if(weeklyVsYearlyVsQuarterly.upper() == "W"):
    yearlyValue = initialValue * 52
    monthlyValue = round(float(yearlyValue / 12),2)
  elif (weeklyVsYearlyVsQuarterly.upper() == "Y"):
    yearlyValue = initialValue
    monthlyValue = round(float(yearlyValue / 12),2)
  elif (weeklyVsYearlyVsQuarterly.upper() == "M"):
    yearlyValue = initialValue * 12
    monthlyValue = initialValue
  elif (weeklyVsYearlyVsQuarterly.upper() == "Q"):
    yearlyValue = initialValue * 4
    monthlyValue = round(float(yearlyValue / 12),2)
  return monthlyValue, yearlyValue
```